# Selecting okay button automatically in a pop-up box with powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am creating a PowerShell script to access a Sybase IQ Server. Normally with an average database I would be doing this through isql which eliminates the UI. But since this is a data warehouse it appears that I have a UI to fight with.

```
dbisql -c "uid=$usrID;pwd=$pwd;eng=iq_datawarehouse; links=tcpip(host=$ip;port$port)"
```

The above code brings up a UI but since this is connecting to a server through a local machine comes the issue with a confirmation box. This script needs to be completely automated so the UI that appears needs to auto select "Okay" to proceed.

Taking from Nate Hekman's registering, finding, and sending commands to a window I have been able to get the script to work most of the time.

```
    $pinvokes = @'
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr Connect(string className, string Connect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
'@
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $pinvokes -Name NativeMethods -Namespace MyUtils
    $hwnd = [MyUtils.NativeMethods]::FindWindow("Connect")
    [MyUtils.NativeMethods]::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd)
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

The issue here is when I run this the SendWait("{Enter}") executes prematurely resulting in creating a line break in PowerShell ISE 60% of the time.

My question here is how would you go about streamlining this to make it more effective and not a hit and miss gamble? Is there a way to select okay rather than sending "Enter" after the window has been identified and brought to the foreground?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this help?  http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Comment: I had a similar case notre long ago. I choose autoIT http://www.autoitscript.com/site/ to accomplish this task. It s a nice toolto interact with UI.

Comment: I am very new to PowerShell (1 month) so I am not familiar with WASP but as soon as I saw your post I ran to grab it. But I haven't been able to get it working with PowerShell 3. WASP does look like it would be perfect for my needs. I will research further and see if I can get it compatible with PowerShell 3. 

Kaysax, That website is blocked by our systems admin for some reason so I will need to check that website from an outside network and get back with you.

Comment: I agree with the AutoIT recommendation. Works awesomely.